# Spartacus- Consignment roll back

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Any input on this

[SourceOrderAction] Process: order-process-00002001-1603978375652 in step SourceOrderAction
[SourceOrderAction] Sourcing from Location: 'Kobe Sannomiya Terminal Hotel'
[SourceOrderAction]         Product [553637]: 'NV10'        Quantity: '1'
[SourceOrderAction] Start Consignment sub-process: 'cons00002001_0_ordermanagement'
[SourceOrderAction] Order was successfully sourced
[ProcessengineTaskRunner] Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

it is happening while consignment process, consignment and consignment process creates and then rollback, In AbstractPlatformTransactionManager , it seems process's transaction is getting marked as roll back globally

It is happening in OOB spartacus B2C

Comment: Still waiting for answer on this..

Answer (score 0):

We have to run the impexes to enable users , which will allow the fulfillment and consignment and its process will not roll back